Need help on TeX4ht (not sure where the errors belongs)
I have tried with:
\documentclass[journal,comsoc,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{wrapfig,colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color, soul}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\title{Efficient generation of realistic guided wave signals for reliability estimation}
\author{Panpan Xu, Robin Jones, Georgios Sarris, and Peter Huthwaite  \IEEEmembership{}
\thanks{This work was supported by GW4SHM, EU Horizon 2020 H2020-MSCA-ITN-2019, Grant No. 860104.}
\thanks{Panpan Xu, Georgios Sarris, and Peter Huthwaite are with the Non-Destructive Evaluation Group, Mechanical Engineering Department, Imperial College London, SW7 2AZ London, UK. (e-mail: p.xu20@imperial.ac.uk, p.huthwaite@imperial.ac.uk).}
\thanks{Robin Jones is with Guided Ultrasonics Ltd., Brentford, TW8 8HQ, UK (e-mail: robin.jones@guided-ultrasonics.com).}
}


\thispagestyle{empty} 
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

% textwidth in cm: \printinunitsof{cm}\prntlen{\textwidth} 18.13275cm
Across non-destructive testing (NDT) and structural health monitoring (SHM), accurate knowledge of the systems' reliability for detecting defects, such as Probability of Detection (POD) analysis is essential to enabling widespread adoption. Traditionally this relies on access to extensive experimental data to cover all critical areas of the parametric space, which becomes expensive, and heavily undermines the benefit such systems bring. In response to these challenges, reliability estimation based on numerical simulation emerges as a practical solution, offering enhanced efficiency and cost-effectiveness. Nevertheless, precise reliability estimation demands that the simulated data faithfully represents the real-world performance. In this context, a numerical framework tailored to generate realistic signals for reliability estimation purposes is presented here, focusing on the application of guided wave SHM for pipe monitoring. It specifically incorporates key characteristics of real signals: random noise and coherent noise caused by the imbalance in transducer performance within guided wave monitoring systems. The effectiveness of our proposed methodology is demonstrated through a comprehensive comparative analysis between simulation-generated signals and experimental signals both individually and statistically. Furthermore, to assess the reliability of a guided wave system in terms of the inspection range for pipe monitoring, a series of POD analyses using simulation-generated data were conducted. The comparison of POD curves derived from ideal and realistic simulation data underscores the necessity of considering coherent noise for accurate POD curve calculations. Moreover, the POD analysis based on realistic simulation-generated data provides a quantitative estimation of the inspection range with more details compared to the current industry practice. Our presented framework offers a pioneering approach to generate realistic guided wave signals, thereby facilitating the practical assessment of the reliability of guided wave monitoring systems. This advancement also has the potential to effectively address challenges related to data scarcity in broader applications requiring high-fidelity data, such as the training of machine learning models for damage identification from complex signals for all aspects of ultrasonic inspections with both guided and bulk waves.

\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Coherent noise, guided wave monitoring, realistic signal generation, reliability estimation, transducer imbalance 
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}

\subsection{Random noise}\label{randomNoise}

The incorporation of random noise involves a statistical analysis of
the noise collected in the representative experiments, which is
specific to the ambient environments and measurement system employed.
In this study, random noise can be effectively modelled using
Gaussian white noise with a limited bandwidth, as described in
\ref{randomNoise}. The RMS level of the random noise across transducer channels follows the distribution described in \protect\ref{Figure 5a}.

\end{document}

If I remove the line \ref{randomNoise}, then it's working fine, I am not sure where the error was. Please advise.

The error seems to be caused by the redefinition of the \mbox command by TeX4ht, which is not robust. IEEEtran uses \mbox to format subsection  references, so it is written to the aux file and then it results in errors.
This version of IEEEtran.4ht should fix it:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% IEEEtran.4ht                      2009-05-21-09:32 %
% Copyright (C) 2009             Eitan M. Gurari         %
%                                                        %
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the %
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either %
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any   %
% later version. The latest version of this license is   %
% in                                                     %
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt                %
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions %
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.                  %
%                                                        %
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".%
%                                                        %
% This Current Maintainer of this work                   %
% is Eitan M. Gurari.                                    %
%                                                        %
% If you modify this program your changing its signature %
% with a directive of the following form will be         %
% appreciated.                                           %
%            \message{signature}                         %
%                                                        %
%                             gurari@cse.ohio-state.edu  %
%                 http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\immediate\write-1{version 2009-05-21-09:32}

\let\twocolumn\onecolumn
\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
\let\@restonecolfalse\@restonecoltrue

\long\def\:temp#1{\leavevmode\hbox{\a:mbox {#1}\b:mbox}}
\HLet\mbox:temp\:temp
\DeclareRobustCommand\mbox[1]{\mbox:temp{#1}}

\Hinput{IEEEtran}
\endinput


A bigger issue is that this class doesn't load any default LaTeX class, and it defines all basic commands from scratch. In the process, it also redefines a lot of internal LaTeX commands, so loading of default TeX4ht configurations results in fatal errors. So the document you get is not correctly marked up, even if it looks visually more or less OK. Adding full TeX4ht support would be a lot of work, so I cannot guarantee that I will be able to do that. I have a lot of requests at the moment, so I don't have a capacity for that now.
This is the result:


Works beautifully, thanks
